# Return a fully-allocated array of pairs with other misc. info in Java

Tags: java, arrays, class

I have to write a method that traverses a huge object's contents which are spread across machines and need to return this:

- starting index in the object's struct(ex: if it has 10 pieces/blocks I can return piece/block 3-7)
- offset within the first piece
- list/array of `pair < id of each piece, size of each piece >` (not map - `I've been clearly told not to use Map or Map.Entry`)

Quoting exact words, I'm required to return `fully-allocated array corresponding to the block range`.

`Thought #1`: The starting index and offset are to be returned once, the option to create a class with

- index
- offset
- id
- size

and returning an array of this will be providing redundant information plus, adding 8 bytes every entry is huge waste of memory.

`Thought #2`: I could create a data class with (id and size) and return another class with array of this smaller class + index & offset, but in this case the existence of my data class will be just to contain values which doesn't seem v. prudent.

`Thought #3`:I've heard multiple times that people resort to arrays when need to return pairs.  I don't know how to do that?

Comment: I don't understand what you find wrong with your thought #2 (except I would use a collection instead of an array).

Comment: Why would I use a collection? My array should be fixed in size only then the consumer would be able to get a fair estimate of # of blocks received. I don't need any other advanced features of a collection.

Comment: On the other hand, since it was mentioned how on earth can I create an array of pairs?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to create, basically, a data structure. There is a single way to do that in Java: use classes.

Your first thought is wrong: you must return a single index, and a single offset, and multiple pairs. It's thus wrong to put all the fields in a single class, since the cardinality of the fields is not the same. In particular, if there is 0 pair to return, you would be very embarrassed.

Your second thought maps exactly to what you must return. Except I would use a collection (List or Set) instead of an array:

```
public class Result {
    private int index;
    private int offset;
    private Set<Piece> pieces;

    ...
}

public class Piece {
    private String id;
    private int size;

    ...
}
```

Why use a collection rather than a `Piece[]` array: because there's a good chance that you don't know the number of pieces before the traversal. Because a List or Set has many useful methods that an array doesn't have. Because a `Set<Piece>` clearly says that there are no duplicate elements, which is not the case with an array of Piece.

The third thought consists in using an `Object[]` containing 2 elements (or an `int[]` of two elements, if both the ID and the size are of type `int`, for example), to hold the information about a Piece. But that is ugly and unreadable: it's not obvious at all what the array contains, in which order, and what their type is. And you can't add any useful method like you could with a Piece class.

Java is an OO language. Use classes and objects. Use encapsulation.

Comment: So, in the third option you create one int[] for each block info? and then an array to hold all sub-arrays..that's v ugly indeed.

Comment: Now that we're here..may I ask another Java specific question in same thread? or should I create a different one?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18420725/java-method-takes-a-size-parameter-does-some-work-and-return-a-reference-and-up