# Java method takes a size parameter, does some work and return a reference and updates the size, reference and size to be used by method 2

Tags: java, reference, arguments, return-value

- I have an array of variable sized blocks on which I want to perform some business logic.
- I have to work with a 'size' parameter which identifies num of bytes (total - in all the blocks) to be parsed and processed and after processing the result should be list of blocks and their sizes.
- I wrote a recursive logic which extremely neatly parses the data but for it to be so neat I had to limit it to function along block boundaries (aligned).
- That seemed fine also because the only non-aligned blocks I'll have will be the first and last. My previous function can very well handle the last block but not the first one.
- So, I write a different function to handle non-aligned offset in the block.
- My DS:

  ```
  class BlockInfo {
      private long blockID;
      private long blockSize;
  }

  public class BlockIDSet {
      private long offset;
      private int firstBlockIndex;
      private List<BlockInfo> resultSet;
  }
  ```
- Job of first function: if starting offset is not aligned, parse the remaining bytes from the offset to the end of the block and return `firstBlockIndex`, `single BlockInfo object` and update the `remaining size (numBytes)`.
- The second function will consume the `remaining size`, start from `firstBlockIndex +1` and return a `list of BlockInfo objects`.

In C++, it is very common for us to pass arguments as reference and update their values in function calls so the updated values can be used later. As much as I read, Java recommends not to do so. [Related Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/724199/should-java-method-arguments-be-used-to-return-multiple-values). How should I achieve this? Or is my design flawed and I should re-do it?

Comment: You may define a class, pass an instance of this class as argument, and update this object from the called method. You can also leave the arguments untouched, and return a custom object from your method. Java is an OO language. Define classes and use objects.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to pass `numBytes` between function calls you have to choice:

Using function return value

```
numBytes = 1024;
numBytes = numBytes - firstJob(numBytes, ...);
secondJob(numBytes,...);
```

or [Apache commons-lang Mutable objects](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-2.6/org/apache/commons/lang/mutable/MutableInt.html)

```
MutableInt numBytes = new MutableInt(1024);
firstJob(numBytes, ...);
secondJob(numBytes, ...);
```

and inside functions you can change integer value inside mutable object without change `numBytes` reference (you can't do that in Java)

---

Else, if you want to change a `BlockInfo` or `BlockIDSet` (passed as parameter) properties you can do without problem.

```
public void firstJob(BlockInfo bi) {
  bi.blockSize = 23;
}
```

Comment: That's what I'm doing.. :(

Comment: Why :( ? This is a common pratice in Java.

Comment: I've started using java recently and coming from C++.. Passing by reference was extremely intuitive to me..so :(.. `Paradigm` shift!